# Do native speakers use "ultima" and "proxima" frequently in spoken English?

Tags: word-request

I have noticed that the words **ultima** and **proxima** are rarely used.

How do native speakers use these?

Comment: I notice you asked about spoken language, as if you've seen these used in written. I've never seen them used as normal words in written English. Any chance you've confused them with the similar words "ultimate" and "proximate"?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

"Ultimate", "penultimate", "proximate", and "approximate" are English words.

"[Ultimate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ultimate)" is common, partly because it is used in advertising.

"[Penultimate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/penultimate)" is less common than "ultimate", partly because nobody wants to advertise that their product is second-best.

"[Approximate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/approximate)" is common, both as an adjective and as a verb.  The adjective "approximate" is more formal than the adjective "rough"; the verb "approximate" is more formal than "make a careful guess" or "come close to".

"[Proximate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proximate)" is not very common.  Both "penultimate" and "proximate" are sometimes used by educated writers.

*[Ultima](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ultima)* and *[proxima](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proxima)* are so rare that they might as well still be Latin words.  Until I looked them up just now, I had no idea that *ultima* specifically referred to the last syllable in a word, instead of generally the "furthest out" thing in a group of things.  The most common use of *ultima* is in the title of the on-line game *[Ultima Online](https://uo.com/)*.  The most common use of *proxima* is in the name of the second-closest star to the Earth, *[Proxima Centauri](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Proxima_Centauri)*.

Comment: I would argue that the spell Ultima across the Final Fantasy and related game series is at least as common/well known as the Ultima game series at this point.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile: That depends on one's particular subculture.  I know ultima from the name "Ultima Thule" in astronomy & history, but nothing about on-line games/

Comment: *"Perhaps it was the penultimate supper?"*

Comment: Penultimate is sometimes used with respect to syllables, e.g., to explain stress in Spanish words.

Comment: I suspect penultimate is more often used incorrectly (as an intensified form of ultimate) than correctly.

Comment: Don't forget _antipenultimate_ :-)

Comment: @AaronF: typo: it's [antepenultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antepenultimate).

Comment: Penultimate doesn't mean "second best", but rather, "next to last"

Comment: @Chad -- In the context of advertising, "ultimate" means "the best so far" or "the final word in _____."  In that context, "penultimate" means either "the one that came before the ultimate ____", or "the one whose rank is not quite the same as the best."  In other words, "second best".

Comment: It's worth noting that many English speakers understand *ultimate* to mean "really great" and *penultimate* to mean "better than ultimate" even though these are not the literal meanings (and in the 2nd case it's laughably wrong).

Comment: @ThePhoton -- Your comment would make a good answer, especially if you can provide a citation for the commonness of the misinterpretation of "penultimate".

Comment: Shouldn't "proximity" get a mention here?

Comment: I find that "penultimate" is occasionally used when talking about TV shows and video games (penultimate episode, penultimate boss), because it's a lot easier to say them "the ep that was right before season finale"

Comment: @ThePhoton I have to wonder if the confusion arose because often in books/tv etc, the climax would occur *before* the last episode/chapter, followed by a resolution/dénouement, so the penultimate episode would in fact be the climax (and more exciting than the "ultimate" episode). A question for english.SE maybe...

Comment: @ThePhoton I have never encountered this confusion ever, anywhere.

Comment: Proximate is *very* common in the legal field, but I very rarely see it outside of the field of law.

Comment: @psmears -- You made a good-faith edit. I owe you an explanation for why I reverted it.  Please keep in mind that edits to posts "put words in the author's mouth".  Even edits that are correct for most contexts are not a good idea if they contradict how the post author interprets something in a particular context.  This answer points out that the meanings of "ultimate" and "penultimate" in the context of advertising are important to how widely those words are used.  Chad and I discussed these meanings in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. No worries about the revert, it was just a suggestion. But my concern is that your answer can be read as saying that "penultimate" is used to mean "second best". I agree that *if* it were used like "ultimate" in an advertising context it *would* imply that - but, as you point out, it *isn't* used that way, so it doesn't ever have that meaning. This being a site for learners of English I think it's worth being as clear as possible to avoid confusion. Can you think of a way of clarifying that point in your answer without detracting from your original intent?

Answer (score 45):

Those both exist as words in English, but with very specialised meanings or very infrequent use. These relate to their meanings in Latin, which are reflected in modern Spanish (and possibly Portuguese, too), albeit with accents on some letters.

***Ultima*** is used in specialised situations to refer to the last syllable of a word.

***Proximo***, the nearest any attested English word comes to *proxima* without being a proper noun, is a little-known term that means "of (the) next month", for example "on the 3rd proximo" means "on the third day of next month". *Ultimo* is correspondingly used (or not) for the previous month.

These are both rather obscure words and most people are not familiar with them. I only know what they mean now because I thought I should look them up before saying "those are not English words".

Don't use them. Well, use *ultima* if you're in the sort of context where other people use it. Don't use it otherwise, and basically no-one uses *proxima* unless they're trying to show off their expansive vocabulary.

Comment: I looked them up and didn't find them in a couple of dictionaries. I should have checked some others before saying "those are not English words".

Comment: @Gustavson I think it is interesting to mention that they are also Spanish words. Are they also uncommon in Spanish?

Comment: No, they are extremely common.

Comment: I suspect that English *proxima* derives purely from people with expensive educations trying to demonstrate that they had a Latin education. *Ultima* as a specialist term is more understandable.

Comment: SamBC, when I was a boy in Britain, a certain way of writing routine business letters was in its death throes, but still lingering on in places. 'yours of the 14th ultimo” meant "your letter dated the 14th of last month". As well as that you had "instant" (this month), and "proximo" (next month), usually abbreviated to e.g. the 14th ult., 23 inst., and 3rd prox. I am told they linger in India.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey interesting!

Comment: I meant to write 23**rd** inst.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Indian English is a very different language from British English, and has retained many words that were common before the end of the Indian Empire but now obsolete in BrE - just like American English has retained many words from before the Declaration of Independence :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey These were also used the same way in AmE centuries ago but few people today understand them.

Comment: I have seen pre-printed response forms which say something like "Dear M_ _______, Thank you for your esteemed favour of _______ ult/inst. We hope to be able to reply soon. Yours faithfully ____________ per pro Company Name Ltd. A clerk would enter and strike out where necessary. Dying out in the 1940s I dare say.

Comment: I have seen the ult/inst in very old legal letters here in the southern US, stuff related to real estate transfers or appraisals in the 1940s. Didn't have the slightest clue what it meant though,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey : The Sydney suburb of Ultimo acquired its name in a curious way."'Ultimo' was originally the name of the estate of Dr John Harris, on 34 acres granted to him by Governor King in 1803. It was named for a clerical error in a legal case against Harris that had prevented him being court-martialled. His offence was listed as 'ultimo' (having occurred in the previous month) when it should have been cited as 'instant' (having occurred in the same month). Harris Street is named in his honour" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimo,_New_South_Wales

Comment: @ColleenV In Spanish (and Portuguese), _última_ and _próxima_ are (the feminine singular forms of) the common words for ‘last’ and ‘next’: _la última/próxima vez_ means ‘the last/next time’, etc. So yes, very common there.

Comment: I've come across the abbreviated *prox.* for next month, and could probably have told you what it was short for, but don't recall ever seeing the full *proxima* used

Comment: @ChrisH:In fact it's not "proximA", it's "[proximO](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proximo)" (and similarly "[ultimO](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ultimo)" for last month...) - it ends in "o" rather than "a" since the Latin word "mensis" (month) is masculine.

Comment: @psmears: Well, whoever 'adopted' them into English must have imported the mistake, because *proxima* is what's documented. *Proximo* might be documented/attested as well, but the *-a* version turns up in references.

Comment: @SamBC: Documented where? I included links to the dictionary (which has "ultimO") in my comment, and I searched for examples of "proximA" meaning "next month" but couldn't find any references except on this page (mostly proximA refers to [a star](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proxima). If you have references to proximA meaning "next month", can you add them in to your answer?

Comment: @psmears huh. You may be right. I'll edit when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @psmears: I clearly noted the difference when I was doing my research, and then forgot it when I went to write it up... fixed now.

Comment: @SamBC: cool, thanks for fixing it - now upvoted :)

Answer (score 20):

> I have noticed that the words ultima and proxima is rarely used.
>
> How native speakers use these?

I know from my knowledge of classical Latin and of Spanish that these words mean 'last' and 'next' respectively.

How do native speakers use these? They don't. I have never used or heard or read these words in English.

**Edit 1**

I see from @SamBC that these words appear in English dictionaries with very specialised meanings. I didn't know those meanings and I will not make any attempt to remember them.

**Edit 2**

It occurs to me that astronomers use 'proxima' as in Proxima Centauri, a red dwarf  star, in the constellation of Centaurus. This is however the *name* of the star and is not used in general conversation by most people unless they happening to be discussing that particular celestial body.

Comment: +1. They are very common in my language too.

Comment: Also, "Ultima" is the name of a series of computer games, from back in the day.

Answer (score 16):

In 18th and 19th century business correspondence, these words, invariably abbreviated as "Ult." and "Prox." were often used to mean mean 'of the last month" and "of the next month". Such a letter might run:

> In your favor of the 19th ult., you proposed delivery on the 20th prox. The supplies are needed by the 10th prox. at the latest.

(Here "favor" was a polite term for "letter addressed to me" now also obsolete.)

I have not seen this usage in any document later than about 1920, and rarely in any later than 1880. Currently I see them only in historical fiction of that period, or in the star name *Proxima Centauri* mentioned in other answers.

Comment: I suspect these are not English, but abbreviations for Latin terms, like et. al. or etc.

Comment: @jamesqf  They probably were, in origin at least. But then i would class "etc" and "etcetera" as fully absorbed into English, as i would "I.e." and "e.g." Of course latinisms were more common in English usage at that period than they are now.

Comment: There was also "inst." for "of this month", which may be slightly better known than the other two. They crop up from time to time in golden age crime fiction, which is where I've seen them.

Comment: @Especially Lime Oh yes I'd forgotten that, it stood for "Instant" I believe. Yes, that is one place to see them, and works just later than Jane Austin and of the same genre are another.

Comment: Reginald Perrin (title character of a sitcom, 1976–79) used “ult.” in dictating letters (at least in the first series).

Comment: I remember Reginald Perrin, but had forgotten his use of "ult." But then he was supposed to be stuffy and old-fashioned, at least at the start of his character arc.

Comment: Technically (and I am being **extremely** pedantic here), those stand for *ultimo* and *proximo*, presumably because the Latin for "month" requires that ending. It is true that they are forms of the same Latin words as *ultima* and *proxima* are, but I would argue that because the declension doesn't occur in English, that they have to enter English as separate words. Quite pedantic, as I said. Have an upvote by way of atonement, because this is good information for someone curious about those words.

Answer (score 5):

Both terms are very solidly examples of jargon (in any sense of the term actually, depending on the context).

---

#### Ultima

'ultima' could be:

- A linguistics term, with the exact single meaning listed in both the OED and Webster's.
- The name of a video game series.
- The name of a spell in the Final Fantasy video games.
- Part of the name of any of a couple of astronomical objects (Ultima Thule being the trivial example).
- Possibly used as part of other terminology in a different field of science, engineering, or mathematics.

There are a handful of other words in English with varying meanings that are derived from the same Latin root as 'ultima':

- 'Ultimate': Pretty widely used in advertising and branding.  Refers to the absolute best version, form, or iteration of something.
- 'Penultimate': Not very widely used outside of academic settings.  Refers to the second-to last instance of something.
- 'Ultimatum': Contextually common.  Used to refer to a truly final offer in negotiations (or similar situations), typically one which if rejected will immediately end negotiations.

There are probably others I've missed.

---

#### Proxima

I've actually not found any definition searching online for this other than the use in astronomy as a clip form of the name of the star Proxima Centauri (MWD doesn't list it, I don't have an OED subscription so I can't check there, dictionary.com lists the astronomy use, and everywhere else I've checked matches either MWD or dictionary.com).  I've not seen it used for any other purpose either (unlike 'ultima', which I've seen multiple times before).

There are, however, also a number of other English words derived from the same Latin root:

- 'Proximal': Used mostly in scientific settings, especially biology and medicine.  Usually used as an antonym to 'distal', occasionally as a synonym for 'proximate'.
- 'Proximate': Also mostly in scientific settings, referring to an object or event that directly follows or precedes a specific reference point in a sequence.
- 'Proximo': Rarely used except in prose.  This is a direct clip of the Latin phrase 'proximo mense', literally 'in the next month', and retains the same meaning.
- 'Approximate': Widely used in mathematics and science, as well as some usage in general speech in it's various forms.  All forms ultimately are variants on the noun 'approximation', and refer to something being close to some other reference point (usually a correct answer to a problem).

I've probably also missed some here too.

Comment: Proxima is used in nearly the Latin sense in medicine. Proximal vs. Distal refer to proximity to the heart, so the distal joint in a finger is the tip, while the proximal one would be the one connecting it to the hand. Pretty sure ultima sees use, too. MDs overtly adopted Latin for jargon.

Answer (score 3):

*Ultima Thule* and *Proxima Centauri* are English in the same way that *Jupiter* or *Homo Sapiens* are English.

They are familiar scientific names for specific things, and would be recognised as such by an English speaker, but they are not English words in and of themselves.

Most astromomical names are derived from Greek, Latin or other ancient languages and are explicitly not English because they are intended for international use.

In the case of the two words you asked about, "Ultima" and "Promima" do apparently exist in English language dictionaries as words, but are not in common useage as stand-alone words and where they are used, the meanings of those words in English are not the same as the Latin meanings intended by the astronomical names.

Answer (score 2):

As a native English speaker, I have never heard those words use "in the wild", except under the following contexts:

Ultima:

- The astronomical body [Ultima Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(486958)_2014_MU69)
- Richard Gariot's computer game series [Ultima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_(series)).

Proxima:

- The star [Proxima Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri).

While you might find some definitions for them in some dictionaries that say otherwise, the words don't really have any general meaning on their own for the common English speaker.

Comment: "In classical and medieval literature, ultima Thule (Latin "farthermost Thule") acquired a metaphorical meaning of any distant place located beyond the "borders of the known world"" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule) this is the primary meaning of "Ultima Thule " in english

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Perhaps to you. I've *never* heard it used that way (hmmmm...OK. I've lived a long literate life, so "never" is strong. I think I read one work of SF once that made reference to that meaning in a place name, just like the Astronomers did with their Trans-Neptunian Object.) There are probably folks walking around who feel as you do, but I'd wager far more don't know that and just know it as something Astronomers mention sometimes, and **both groups are dwarfed by people who'd have no idea at all.**

Comment: I will freely grant that most English speakers have probably never heard of Ultima Thule in any sense. And it does seem that recent web mentions focus on the astronomical object (which i had never heard of before this question came up)., But I read many mentions of "Ultima Thule" as "a place beyond all other places" or as a metaphor for 'the frozen north' decades ago. An entire chapter of Avram Davidson's *Adventures in Unhistory* deals with the long history of this term and the concepts behind it.

Comment: I assume that the astronomical meaning of "Ultima Thule" was derived from the older meaning described by @DavidSiegel.